# Android Studio generate signed apk not working on build 0.3.6 - Giving Error

Tags: android, android-studio

I have never had a problem with this before. When i try and generate signed apk, select my keystore, enter filename, it gives me an error.

Cant find the XXXX-debug-unaligned.apk

I don't have any signing configs or build types setup in my build.gradle because i never needed them. I have always used generate signed apk and it produces my apk.

I did notice before upgrading from 0.3.4 to 0.3.6 i had to choose from debug/release build variants to get it to work. But that was the first time that had happened too. After upgrading to 0.3.6 there are no build variants. Not sure how they got there to start with since i didnt have anything setup in the build.gradle.

I am able to run a gradle assembleRelease to get my apk, but want the generate signed apk working if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this was an issue with 0.3.6 version but i have fixed it

Going into the moduel iml file and changing assembleRelease to assembleDebug. You also have to alter the rest of the iml. here is mine.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$/.." external.system.id="GRADLE" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="android" name="Android">
      <configuration>
        <option name="SELECTED_BUILD_VARIANT" value="Debug" />
        <option name="ASSEMBLE_TASK_NAME" value="assembleDebug" />
        <option name="COMPILE_JAVA_TASK_NAME" value="assembleTest" />
        <option name="SOURCE_GEN_TASK_NAME" value="generateReleaseSources" />
        <option name="ALLOW_USER_CONFIGURATION" value="false" />
        <option name="MANIFEST_FILE_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" />
        <option name="RES_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/res" />
        <option name="RES_FOLDERS_RELATIVE_PATH" value="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res" />
        <option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/assets" />
        <option name="APK_PATH" value="/build/apk/Clean.Multi-debug-unaligned.apk" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
    <facet type="android-gradle" name="Android-Gradle">
      <configuration>
        <option name="GRADLE_PROJECT_PATH" value=":Clean.Multi" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="false">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/debug" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/r/debug" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/aidl/debug" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/rs/debug" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/buildConfig/debug" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/res/rs/debug" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/r/test" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/aidl/test" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/rs/test" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/buildConfig/test" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/res/rs/test" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/aidl" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/assets" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/jni" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/rs" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/res" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/resources" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/aidl" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/assets" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/jni" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/rs" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/aidl" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/assets" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/jni" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/rs" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/res" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/resources" isTestSource="true" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/apk" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/assets" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/bundles" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/dependency-cache" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/incremental" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/libs" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/manifests" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/symbols" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/tmp" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android SDK" jdkType="Android SDK" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="ComGithubGabrielemariottiCardsLibrary050.aar" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="picasso-2.1.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="ComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71800.aar" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="android-async-http-1.4.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="kryo-2.21-all" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="httpclientandroidlib-1.1.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="support-v4-19.0.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="universal-image-loader-1.8.6-with-sources" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="libGoogleAnalyticsServices" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same (or similar) issue, and apparently I was missing the APK_PATH option in the .iml file:
I added this option like this:

```
<?xml [...]
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="android" name="Android">
      <configuration>
[...]
        <option name="APK_PATH" value="/build/apk/<your project name>-defaultFlavor-debug-unaligned.apk" />
```